# NEXT.js how to sync server rendered props in redux state?

Tags: javascript, express, redux, next.js

I  am using getStaticProps to get data from server side. How i can sync it with redux?

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
   return { props: { trans: "Some data"} };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this example - [with-redux](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux).

Here are some notices:

- You should use [Custom App](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app)
- Since you are using [getStaticProps (Static Generation)](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation)
  , you should check the `pages/ssg.js` file.